# Como llamar a una función desde un boton PHP desde HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html, yii2

¡Hola!

Después de una larga espera al fin, me toca desarrollar un ETL (Extracción, Tranformacion y Carga de los datos) utilizando Yii2

Necesito llamar la funcion actionIndex() que esta en la clase ETLController desde el siguiente boton **Extraer**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El siguiente es el codigo del boton **Extraer**

```
<div class="etl-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Extraer', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
        <?= Html::a('Cargar', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-info']) ?>
    </p>

</div>
```

La siguiente es la función que tengo que utilizar al momento de dar click en el boton **Extraer** desde la clase `EtlController.php`

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        // ejecución de la tarea de etl
        Job::start()
        // datos a extraer
        ->extract('table', 'user', [
            'connection' => 'mysql' // Base de datos de donde obtendre los datos, si no viene seteado se utiliza el valor que tiene el campo 'default'
        ]) 
        // transformacion a aplicar a los datos
        ->transform('trim', ['columns' => ['name', 'email']])
        // donde cargare los datos
        ->load('table', 'usuario_dimension_wikieam', [
            'connection' => 'pgsql' // Base de datos a donde voy a insertar los datos
        ]);
    }
```

Esta es la clase donde se encuentra la función

```
class EtlController extends Controller
{

    public function actionEtl(){
        return $this->render('index',[]);
    }


    public $file;
    public function init()
    {
        Etl::config([
            'path' => '/path/to/etl/files',
            'database' => [
                // Base de datos a utilizar
                'default' => 'mysql',

                'connections' => [

                    'mysql' => [
                        'driver' => 'mysql',
                        'host' => 'localhost',
                        'port' => '3306',
                        'database' => 'wikieam',
                        'username' => 'root',
                        'password' => '1234',
                        'charset' => 'utf8',
                        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                    ],

                    'mysql' => [
                        'driver' => 'mysql',
                        'host' => 'localhost',
                        'port' => '3306',
                        'database' => 'tempwikieam',
                        'username' => 'root',
                        'password' => '1234',
                        'charset' => 'utf8',
                        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                    ],

                    'pgsql' => [
                        'driver' => 'pgsql',
                        'host' => 'localhost',
                        'port' => '5432',
                        'database' => 'dwmediawiki',
                        'username' => 'postgres',
                        'password' => 'admin',
                        'charset' => 'utf8',
                        'schema' => 'public',
                    ],

                ],

            ],

        ]);
    }
    public function options($actionID)
    {
        return ['file'];
    }

    public function optionAliases()
    {
        return ['f' => 'file'];
    }

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        // ejecución de la tarea de etl
        Job::start()
        // datos a extraer
        ->extract('table', 'user'); 
        $options = ['columns' => ['user_id','user_name','user_real_name']]
        [
            'connection' => 'mysql' // Base de datos de donde obtendre los datos, si no viene seteado se utiliza el valor que tiene el campo 'default'
        ]
        // transformacion a aplicar a los datos
        ->transform('trim', ['columns' => ['name', 'email']])
        // donde cargare los datos
        ->load('table', 'usuario_dimension_wikieam', [
            'connection' => 'pgsql' // Base de datos a donde voy a insertar los datos
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

//    /**
//     * Lists all etl models.
//     * @return mixed
//     */
//    public function actionIndex()
//    {
//        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
//            'query' => etl::find(),
//        ]);
//
//        return $this->render('index', [
//            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
//        ]);
//    }

    /**
     * Displays a single etl model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new etl model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new etl();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->idetl]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing etl model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->idetl]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing etl model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the etl model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return etl the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = etl::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema o la dificultad que te estás encontrando?

Comment: No estoy presentando ninguna dificultad solamente quiero que al momento se presionar el boton **Extraer** se ejecute la funcion actionIndex()

Comment: en ambos botones estas llamando a la acción create, deberías reemplazarlo por la acción que deseas enlazar. Una buena practica es poner la cadena "controlador/acción" a la hora de generar la ruta, y no solo el nombre de la acción

Comment: Te refieres a que lo llame asi de la siguiente manera `<?= Html::a('Extraer', ['EtlController/actionIndex'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al indicar la ruta del enlace tienes que poner el nombre del controlador sin la parte nombrada "Controller" y la acción sin la parte "action" quedando "controlador/acción" de una forma similiar (según te entiendo) a esto:

`<?= Html::a('Extraer', ['Etl/index'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>`

En el caso de que lo estés creando en la misma vista del controlador, puedes omitir la parte que determina el controlador donde está la acción (Etl en este caso).

Aún así, personalmente crearía una nueva acción solo para esto y plantearía el uso de ajax si procediera.

Para crear una acción, dentro del controlador antepones "action" al nombre de la acción como por ejemplo:

`public function actionExtraer()
{
...
}`

El resto sería darle cuerpo al bloque con lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 0):

Si tu Html esta en la view de "etl"  el botón debería ser algo así

```
<?= Html::a('Extraer', ['extraer'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
```

y el controller deberia tener una función llamada así "actionExtraer".

De lo contrario si estas trabajando en otra view  con modelo y controlador diferente   entonces deberías programar la acción del botón en el controlador de tu view  y a partir de hay  escribir el código que tienes en "ecl"