# Error sintaxis al crear funcion PHP

Tags: php, yii2, function

Buen día, tengo este problema al ejecutar una función en PHP, si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradezco de antemano

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
   public function actionIndex()
    {
        // ejecución de la tarea de etl
        $job = new Job();
        Job::start()
        // datos a extraer
        ->extract('table', 'user'); 
        $options = ['columns' => ['user_id','user_name','user_real_name']];        
        [
            'connection' => 'mysql' // Base de datos de donde obtendre los datos, si no viene seteado se utiliza el valor que tiene el campo 'default'
        ],
        // transformacion a aplicar a los datos
        ->transform('trim', ['columns' => ['codigo', 'nombreusuario', 'nombre']])
        // donde cargare los datos
        ->load('table', 'usuario_dimension_wikieam', [
            'connection' => 'pgsql' // Base de datos a donde voy a insertar los datos
        ]);
    }
```

Esta es la clase donde esta la funcion

```
class EtlController extends Controller
{

    public function actionEtl(){
        return $this->render('index',[]);
    }


    public $file;
    public function init()
    {
        Etl::config([
            'path' => '/path/to/etl/files',
            'database' => [
                // Base de datos a utilizar
                'default' => 'mysql',

                'connections' => [

                    'mysql' => [
                        'driver' => 'mysql',
                        'host' => 'localhost',
                        'port' => '3306',
                        'database' => 'wikieam',
                        'username' => 'root',
                        'password' => '1234',
                        'charset' => 'utf8',
                        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                    ],

                    'mysql' => [
                        'driver' => 'mysql',
                        'host' => 'localhost',
                        'port' => '3306',
                        'database' => 'tempwikieam',
                        'username' => 'root',
                        'password' => '1234',
                        'charset' => 'utf8',
                        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                    ],

                    'pgsql' => [
                        'driver' => 'pgsql',
                        'host' => 'localhost',
                        'port' => '5432',
                        'database' => 'dwmediawiki',
                        'username' => 'postgres',
                        'password' => 'admin',
                        'charset' => 'utf8',
                        'schema' => 'public',
                    ],

                ],

            ],

        ]);
    }
    public function options($actionID)
    {
        return ['file'];
    }

    public function optionAliases()
    {
        return ['f' => 'file'];
    }

    function actionIndex()
    {
        // ejecución de la tarea de etl
        $job = new Job();
        Job::start()
        // datos a extraer
        ->extract('table', 'user'); 
        $options = ['columns' => ['user_id','user_name','user_real_name']];        
        [
            'connection' => 'mysql' // Base de datos de donde obtendre los datos, si no viene seteado se utiliza el valor que tiene el campo 'default'
        ]
        // transformacion a aplicar a los datos
        ->transform('trim', ['columns' => ['codigo', 'nombreusuario', 'nombre']])
        // donde cargare los datos
        ->load('table', 'usuario_dimension_wikieam', [
            'connection' => 'pgsql' // Base de datos a donde voy a insertar los datos
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

//    /**
//     * Lists all etl models.
//     * @return mixed
//     */
//    public function actionIndex()
//    {
//        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
//            'query' => etl::find(),
//        ]);
//
//        return $this->render('index', [
//            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
//        ]);
//    }

    /**
     * Displays a single etl model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new etl model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new etl();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->idetl]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing etl model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->idetl]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing etl model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the etl model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return etl the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = etl::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que recibes? No termina de quedar claro en la pregunta.

Comment: En la primera imagen de la pregunta se ve en la linea 97 un error de sintaxis no se aun como solucionarlo

Comment: Si ejecutas el código, ¿qué error te muestra? (si no te muestra ninguno, prueba a poner `error_reporting(E_ALL);` al principio de tu página). El error inicial era que había una coma de más (como poco), pero eso pareces corregirlo en el código añadido después.

Comment: Por cierto, te diría que la respuesta a esta pregunta, está en la otra pregunta que hiciste hace un par de horas. Allá el código se ve bien y sin error de sintaxis.

Comment: Disculpa verifica nuevamente la imagen y mira el error que sale ahora

Comment: En esa imagen se ve dónde está el error, pero no cuál es el error. Si pasas el ratón por encima del icono de error normalmente te sale un mensaje con el problema concreto. Ese mensaje sería de gran ayuda para poder asistirte con el problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estás definiendo la variable `$options` en mitad de una secuencia de operaciones y eso está rompiendo todo.

La solución pasa por mover `$options` fuera de la secuencia de instrucciones y en corregir los parámetros del `extract` (para ponerlos como los tienes puestos en [esta otra pregunta que hiciste](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/145002/250)). Con este par de cambios, ese problema debería resolverse:

```
    // movemos options aqui arriba
    $options = ['columns' => ['user_id','user_name','user_real_name']];  

    // ejecución de la tarea de etl
    $job = new Job();
    Job::start()
    // datos a extraer
    ->extract('table', 'user', [
        'connection' => 'mysql' // Base de datos de donde obtendre los datos, si no viene seteado se utiliza el valor que tiene el campo 'default'
    ])
    // transformacion a aplicar a los datos
    ->transform('trim', ['columns' => ['codigo', 'nombreusuario', 'nombre']])
    // donde cargare los datos
    ->load('table', 'usuario_dimension_wikieam', [
        'connection' => 'pgsql' // Base de datos a donde voy a insertar los datos
    ]);
```